# How to put serving size in USDA API?

Tags: node.js, api, usda-fooddata-central-api

I am using USDA API for personal use but stuck at a problem on [food central website](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/1097512/nutrients), there is an option to select portion or serving size, but I am not sure how to do this with the API.

I have API key as well and have read all its documentation, but didn't find how to use serving size in API.

Neither of these links work:

- `https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=&description=Standard Reference&pageSize=1&dataType=Branded&pageSize=1&householdServingFullText=1 ONZ`
- `https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=api_key&description=Standard Reference&pageSize=1&dataType=Branded&pageSize=1&servingSize=100&servingSizeUnit=g`

By "not working" I mean on hitting API it gives standard response (JSON data) but the serving is not mentioned.

Comment: Your second link contains your API key - should this be secret?

Comment: I should think this issue is sufficiently esoteric to require technical support from the API provider.